# Add an event to a button after adding it with chosen jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>components/chosen_v0.12.0/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
    var config = {
      '.chzn-select'           : {},
      '.chzn-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
      '.chzn-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
      '.chzn-select-no-results': {no_results_text:"Can't find your company? <input type='button' id='test' class='submit' value='button'/>"},
      '.chzn-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }

$('#test').on('click',function(){
    alert('Clicked');
})
```

I need to add a button in case there is no result the drop down i can do extra staff apart from just displaying the message.If i modify the choosen.jquery.js it is working fine but the issue is am using the jquery in many pages and i only want to modify it to a particular page

This is how i modify the choosen.jquery.js

```
 Chosen.prototype.no_results = function(terms) {
  var no_results_html;
  no_results_html = $('<li class="no-results">' + this.results_none_found + '"<span><button id="addCompany" class="submit">ADD</button></span>"</li>');
  no_results_html.find("span").first().html(terms);
  addnewCompany();
  return this.search_results.html(no_results_html);

};

function addnewCompany(){
  $('#addCompany').on('click',function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
}
```

What am i doing wrong with the way am picking the id yet the `$('#test').on('click',fn(){})` should work even if the DOM has loaded?

Comment: Note that the call to `.html(terms)` is changing the contents of the span and may be removing the button entirely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

`$(document).on("click", "#test", function() {alert('clicked'); });`
This idea came from one of the developers but i didn't understand why he removed the answer. The issue was the `.on('click',function(){})` binding is not comprehensive enough so from the ideas load the entire document then select specific element `

```
    var config = {
      '.chzn-select'           : {},
      '.chzn-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
      '.chzn-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
      '.chzn-select-no-results': {no_results_text:"Can't find your company? <input type='button' id='test' class='submit' value='button'/>"},
      '.chzn-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }

     $(document).on("click", "#test", function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });
```

`.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the event before the element is in the DOM :

```
addnewCompany(); //Line that add the event
return this.search_results.html(no_results_html); //Line that append the element on the DOM.
```

Invert them :

```
this.search_results.html(no_results_html);
addnewCompany();
return this.search_results;
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
no_results_html.find("span").first().html(terms);
```

is changing the contents of the span - unless `terms` contains an element with id `addCompany`, there's nothing left to bind to.  In addition to this, a slightly different approach is to bind to the element directly, rather than trying to do it afterwards:

```
chosen.prototype.no_results = function(terms) {
  var no_results_html;
  no_results_html = $('<li class="no-results">' + this.results_none_found + '"<span><button id="addCompany" class="submit">ADD</button></span>"</li>');
  no_results_html.find("span").first().html(terms);
  //bind directly to the #addCompany element at this point
  no_results_html.find("#addCompany").click(function() {
    alert('clicked');
  }

  return this.search_results.html(no_results_html);

};
```

Comment: `.find('#id')` usually looks strange, but not in this case. +1 for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider delegated binding, you can do this by using jQuery "on" i.e.

```
 $("#parentDivOfControlsIWantToBindClickTo").on("click", "a", function() {blah;});
```

Where the first parameter is the event, the second is the selector to bind and the third is obviously what you wish to execute.

What this does is delegate the click event binding to jQuery core, which will monitor the parent item for DOM changes requiring click (or whatever you choose) binding for you automatically.

[See the documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thanks exactly what i wanted. ` $(document).on("click", "#test", function() {
            alert('clicked');
        });`

Comment: I'd not use an ID directly in an "on" binding, maybe a class or a tag, so you have the ability to add more elements later.